# Turbine not working with spring boot 2.0.6 and spring cloud Finchley.SR1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I am trying to implement a simple service which will use turbine, but it doesn't work - turbine not getting any data from other Hystrix-used services.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=5000
spring.application.name=turbine-aggregator
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
turbine.app-config=weather-app
turbine.cluster-name-expression='default'
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.EnableTurbine;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbine

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I can see in the output that it recognize my Hystrix-used app:
[click here for snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lznR.png)

but in turbine stream it looks empty:
[click here for snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXSHN.png)

If someone know what I did in the wrong way please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end - it was my fault.
Since the Hystrix client had an older version of spring boot/cloud it "broadcast" the hystrix stream on ../hystrix.stream, but in the version which I used for turbine it aggregated streams from ../**actuator**/hystrix.stream.
So I just updated the versions in my Hystrix client.